# How can I display RSS feed including images with zRSSFeed without it animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

Hi I am using zRSSFeed for a website and I want a basic RSS feed but with images included.  The only way I found to include images is with the ticker script.

Here is the basic rss feed - http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example.html

Here is the ticker rss image feed - http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_images.html

Here is the zRSSFeed website - http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code you have at the moment please?

Comment: I don't have any code as I don't know how to do it..

Comment: I just need the script code, my html code is irrelevant